# How to override bootstrap input box style in table?

Tags: css, html, input

I would like to get default input box style when the input box is shown in a table cell.

The problem is that the cell expands itself when the input box is shown.

Comment: You are going to need to provide relevant HTML/CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: I need more information about your problem. Show some code.

Comment: @JoshC http://dwthread.tk/keys/wtf.html - click on 'Add a description'

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS `.desc input {
width: auto;
}`

Comment: @koala_dev done! still not working tho :(

Comment: Then you need to set a fixed width for the column, add this `.desc {
width: 290px;
}`