# How to override bootstrap styles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to change simple CSS properties in the default theme that comes with a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application in Visual Studio 2013. In particular I need to change the navigation menu's background color.

I have located via Firebug this property and its new value should be:

```
.navbar-inverse { background-color: #5B80A5}
```

I initially attempted to add the override CSS line in `Site.css` because I noticed these lines in `BundleConfig.cs`:

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

However the nav menu's background color didn't change.

I then searched for `.navbar-inverse` in my solution and the search returned:

```
Web\Content\bootstrap-theme.css(240):.navbar-inverse {
Web\Content\bootstrap-theme.css(249):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {
Web\Content\bootstrap-theme.css(259):.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
Web\Content\bootstrap-theme.css(260):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
Web\Content\bootstrap-theme.css.map(1):{"version":3,"file":"bootstrap-theme.css","sources":["less/theme.less","less/mixins/vendor-prefixes
Web\Content\bootstrap-theme.min.css(5): */.btn-default,.btn-primary,.btn-success,.btn-info,.btn-warning,.btn-danger{text-shadow:0 -1px 0 r
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4190):.navbar-inverse {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4194):.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4197):.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4198):.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4202):.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4205):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4208):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4209):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4213):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4214):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4215):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4219):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4220):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4221):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4225):.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4228):.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4229):.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4232):.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4235):.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4236):.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4239):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4240):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4241):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4246):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4249):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4252):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4255):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4256):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4260):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4261):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4262):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4266):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4267):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4268):  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4273):.navbar-inverse .navbar-link {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4276):.navbar-inverse .navbar-link:hover {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4279):.navbar-inverse .btn-link {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4282):.navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4283):.navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4286):.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4287):fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4288):.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(4289):fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6207):.navbar-inverse { background-color: #F7931A}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6208):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navba
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6209):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.ope
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6212):.navbar-inverse { background-image: none; }
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6214):.navbar-inverse { border-color: #BD7014}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6215):.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand { color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6216):.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover { color: #9E601B}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6217):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6218):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #FDFFF7}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6219):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.op
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6220):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6223):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-top-color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6224):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-top-color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6225):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css(6226):.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF}
Web\Content\bootstrap.css.map(1):{"version":3,"file":"bootstrap.css","sources":["bootstrap.css","less/normalize.less","less/print.less","l
Web\Content\bootstrap.min.css(5): *//*! normalize.css v3.0.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-s
```

I added the custom CSS line at the end of each of the above files but still, nothing happened. I rebuilt the project each time, cleared the cache in my browser, but nothing changed.

Any idea of how to override default boostrap styles? It's driving me nuts!

Similar questions that didn't really help:

[Overriding bootstrap styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410185/overriding-bootstrap-styles),
[How to override bootstrap input box style in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675976/how-to-override-bootstrap-input-box-style-in-table),
[Cant override bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331453/cant-override-bootstrap)

Comment: Add this `.navbar-inverse { background-color: #5B80A5}` at the bottom of `~/Content/site.css`. Remeber to refresh yor css file (ctrl+r in browser)

Comment: @py3r3str that was the first thing I tried, you are right because I mistyped `styles.css` instead of `site.css`, I updated my question, thanks.

Comment: In my newly created project it works like a charm;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your custom class that contains your styles for `.navbar-inverse` class more specific than bootstrap's class. You can add a class to your `<body>` tag and use that to prefix your custom overrides.

```
.myCustomStyle .navbar-inverse
```

If you can't edit your HTML you can use the obvious tags that every html document has:

```
body .navbar-inverse
```

will also make your styles more specific, but for code readability rather use the first approach.

Than you don't have to worry any more on where your file is placed since CSS specificity will always override bootstraps classes + you can always be sure that it is your class by it's name prefix, which makes further debugging much more easier.

Comment: Thanks, this one seems to work! However I still don't get how I should do it without a custom CSS class, what am I doing wrong in my description above?

Comment: @DougPeters check your html source head in browser and check if site.css is really added after bootstrap.css to make sure your Include really adds items in that order. Also check in dev tools where is your class referenced and which bootstrap line overrides it - generally if you copy exact same bootstrap class and apply it in you own css and call it after you call bootstrap css it works 100%.

Answer (score 6):

File Name is not valid - use "Site.css" not "site.css". I also had this issue and resolved it this way without any other change...

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/Site.css"));
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in Visual Studio. In order to make use CSS for the whole site, the file name (in BundleConfig.cs) has to be the up case `Site.css` and not the lower case `site.css`. As far as I know, Visual Studio nor Windows play attention to the case of filename.

Answer (score 1):

[_layout.cshtml CSS order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZaVB.png)

If you place the CSS reference before the bootstrap, it will make the custom CSS priority over the bootstrap. If you look I have the site.css reference above the bootstrap.min.css reference. This is in the Shared/_Layout.cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css.
Similar question here
[CSS changes on MVC App not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357641/css-changes-on-mvc-app-not-working)